# memory leaks on NSMutableArray

Tags: ios7, ios6

I am working with instrument tool to identifying and fixing the memory leaks.I am not sure why instrument is showing leaks in NSMutableArray:"PriceArr" and "KSKPrice" object in below code :

```
NSArray *pricesJson =  [jsonDict valueForKeyConvertingNSNullToNil:@"prices"];
    **NSMutableArray *pricesArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];**
    for (NSDictionary *priceJson in pricesJson) {
        **KSKPrice *price = [[KSKPrice alloc] initWithJSON:priceJson];**
        [pricesArr addObject:price];
        [price release];

    }
    self.prices = pricesArr;
```

I have also tried with NSMutableArray *pricesArr = [NSMutableArray array] but instrument is always showing leaks.

Here is the dealloc method where i am releasing array correctly:

```
 (void)dealloc {
    [_image release];
    [_identifier release];
    [_calories release];
    [_prices release];
    [_name release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first obvious thing I want to ask is, why aren't you using ARC?  Just wondering if you have any doubts about it's abilities or if you have technical problems switching over.  ARC would definitely alleviate this problem for you.

Second thing I want to mention...I don't understand what your for loop is for.  Why can't you just do something like this.

```
// I'm not sure, but i think this should just automatically add the dicts to a mutable array
NSMutableArray * pricesArray = (NSMutableArray *)[jsonDict valueForKeyConvertingNSNullToNil:@"prices"];


// If that doesn't work, this is another better solution
NSArray * pricesJson =  [jsonDict valueForKeyConvertingNSNullToNil:@"prices"];
NSMutableArray * pricesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:pricesJson];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the life cycle for your property for 'self.prices' is correct. Assuming your property is set to retain the object, not releasing it in -(void)dealloc would cause both the mutable array and it's contents to leak. You didn't post that code here, so I can't know for sure.

Comment: Hmm, only thing I can really say now is to run the static code analyzer in Xcode.